# Can I work with git locally and sync to Plastic SCM server

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, plasticscm

I understand that a sync can happen between the git hosting services but I would like to know if it is possible to use git locally and then set it up in such a way that I can sync with the Plastic SCM server.

Ie the inverse of what gitsync does...my central share is a Plastic SCM instance and my local instance is git

The reason is all my working environments are already setup to use git and since my git location should just be able to be seen as another git location is it possible to point Plastic to that and not BitBucket or GitHub per say?

Answer (score 4):

Plastic SCM needs a git server to perform a sync. If you want to sync a local git repo, I would recommend you to run a daemon in the parent folder of your git repo:

```
git daemon --export-all --base-path=. --reuseaddr --enable=receive-pack
```

This way, when yourun the sync from the Plastic SCM side, the git repo will be reachable.

```
git://gitserver/gitRepoName
```

Comment: Okay thanks will try that out and see how that goes...seems like it should do the job

Comment: We're working on a plastic "git server" right now. We even have a working demo: https://youtu.be/R1hXyAqRxFA. But we need to polish it a little bit more before it goes public. Once it gets out, you'll be able to push/pull from a git client to a plastic server :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Plastic SCM GitServer](https://www.plasticscm.com/gitserver/index.html) to push/pull directly from Git to Plastic. It means any git-compatible tool an now be directly plugged to Plastic using the Git protocol.